# Exercise List Excecution Android with Java

Tags: java, android

Hi Im trying to implement an exercise execution list where each exercise should change background color representing that thats the current exercise running every T time for each exercise. I wanted to know how to implement the action of waiting T time until the exercise finish to highlight the next one.
I have something like this, but blocking the thread is not doing the trick.

```
 ArrayList<ExerciseData> exercises;
        ExerciseData ex;
        int curr = 0;
        int cycleSize = warmUpAdapter.getItemCount();
        exercises = (ArrayList<ExerciseData>) warmUpAdapter.getExerciseList();

        while( curr < cycleSize ){
            ex = exercises.get(curr);
            ex.setRunning(true);
            warmUpAdapter.notifyItemChanged(curr);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ex.setRunning(false);
            warmUpAdapter.notifyItemChanged(curr);
            curr++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `postDelayed` method of [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler):

```
private static Handler handler = new Handler();

private void doExercise(final int curr){
    ArrayList<ExerciseData> exercises = (ArrayList<ExerciseData>) warmUpAdapter.getExerciseList();
    if (curr >= exercises.size()){
        System.out.println("Finished");
        return;
    }
    final ExerciseData ex = exercises.get(curr);
    ex.setRunning(true);
    System.out.println("Running exercise " + curr);
    warmUpAdapter.notifyItemChanged(curr);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ex.setRunning(false);
            warmUpAdapter.notifyItemChanged(curr);
            doExercise(curr + 1);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

... call later to start exercises:
doExercise(0);
```